# How I can to set dataset of an Crystal report in C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, dataset

**I am trying to do set datasource for the Crystal Report object

I have a Crystal Report and I have included it in one field and I made this code to send him the Dataset in order to display the data, but when I go down it appears to me an annoying error message and I don't know what the problem is**

[Image of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVT0O.jpg)

**This is The Main Code**

```
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select Patient_ID from Patients", f8conect);

        OleDbDataAdapter dr = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        f8conect.Close();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dr.Fill(ds);
        CrystalReport2 CR2 = new CrystalReport2();
        CR2.SetDataSource(ds);
        Form p = new Print(CR2);
        p.Show();
```

**In Print Form I was put This code in it**

```
    CrystalReport2 CR2;

    public Print(CrystalReport2 S_CR2)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CR2 = S_CR2;
    }

    private void Print_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CR2;
    }
```

Comment: The database is not returning any data from your query.

Comment: No 
It is returning data of one filed only.

Comment: What is your connection string? The first column in OLEDB is sometimes used as a Row Header and with JET/ACE I've seen some unusual things happen with fi

Comment: This is my connection object:-
------------------------------------------------------------
OleDbConnection f8conect = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=DB_1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;");
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: What version of Office do you have?  You may need to change the 12.0.  Try some of the extended options like IMEX = 1.  See https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/

Comment: My Deer... I'm use Access 2016 And My connection is True, It is work, The problem it's only with setdatasource of Crystal Report

Comment: Access 2016 is version 16.0 (not 12.0).  The ACE comes with OFFICE and is in a file like : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\ACEDAO.dll.  The version has to be the same as the version of Office.  There is also a CrystalReport Interop which has to be same version as Office.  See : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1ea29b08-c781-4dc2-9636-bb67c7bbbe11/project-with-crystal-report-com-interop-reference-wont-compile-under-vs2015?forum=msbuild

Comment: Thank you ... but the sentence contacting the database and the contact object work well for me, and the information that I need is brought in every time, and even the Crystal Report works for me well and brings data if I rely on its own data source, and even I have tried to I pass values ​​for Parameter Filed and the command has succeeded. I just face a problem when I send a dataset to the Crystal Report through SetDataSource where I see an error during the program’s execution process (only when executing this part) and the rest of the program is completely running.

Comment: You need to run with the compatible versions.  Just because some of the code runs doesn't mean everything will work.

Comment: Do you have Facebook or Telegram ?... If you have can you put URL here?